# SSAS Calculated Measure for Same Weekday Last Year

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've got a Date dimension and a Fact table containing sales by day. I'm trying to do an easy same period last year calculated measure but I can't get it to work. Using the `ParallelPeriod` function obviously doesn't work as this is not getting the same weekday for last year and sometimes has no value at all.

I have an extra date attribute (`PrevDateKey`) on my date dimension pointing to the correct day of last year. Is there any way I could use this in a calculated measure?

There's currently a relationship between the Date Dimension and the Sales Fact.

> DATE DIM <-> FACT SALE (DateKey) = (SaleDateKey)

So the same date dimension would also have a `PrevDateKey` that could be linked to the fact but obviously I don't want to duplicate the Measure group.

```
(PrevDateKey) = (DateKey)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you need to use a combination of the Properties function and the StrToMember function in your calculated measure.

Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE 
 MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[PrevMemberKey] AS
        [Date].[Calendar Date].Currentmember.Properties('PrevDateKey')

CREATE 
  MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Previous Sales] AS
        (
        STRTOMEMBER('[Date].[Calendar Date].&['+[Measures].[PrevMemberKey]+']'),
        [Measures].[Sales]
        )
```

You may need to rename 'PrevDateKey' to whatever you've named it in your Cube dimension.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good start. I'm facing an issue that if I don't choose the Date hierarchy on the Date level for the rows in a select, the Last Year value is not displayed properly. I want to run a query with a where clause on any date level hierarchy and just showing summary values.